# Sorting objects alphabetically using a comparator?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of book objects alphabetically by title using `Collections.sort`, when I run this, it doesn't seem to give me any way to output the data.

```
public static void SortBooks(Scanner sc, ArrayList<Book> books) {
    Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<Book>() {
        public int compare(Book q1, Book q2) {
            return q1.getBookTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(q2.getBookTitle());
        } 
    });
}
```

Would anybody have a clue on how I could output this data to the console using `System.out.println()`?

Comment: Besides `System.out.println(books);`?

Comment: This is just a method. Feel free to add extra code in your Comparator.

Comment: That gives me "cannnot refer to the non final local variable books defined in an enclosing scope"s

Comment: oh just put `final List<Book> books` in your method parameter.

Comment: @d1234 you should be printing it out after the `Collections.sort` is finished, not inside the `compare` method.  There's no need to make anything final.  `sort` modifies the list, it doesn't do any outputting itself; all you need to do is let it modify the list, then output the list.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help guys, the method was sorting the strings but i didnt bother to look at the list after it was sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness:

```
public static void SortBooks(Scanner sc, ArrayList<Book> books) {
    Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<Book>() {
        public int compare(Book q1, Book q2) {
            // don't put it in here
            return q1.getBookTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(q2.getBookTitle());
        } 
    });
    // put it here, after the sort
    System.out.println(books);
}
```

You can, of course, produce fancier output by iterating over books and printing each member in some particular way.

```
for ( Book b : books ) {
    System.out.println("Book: " + b.getBookTitle());
}
```

or similar.

Comment: FYI, in a more complete program, you'd probably actually not do the print in `SortBooks()` itself, but instead after the call to `SortBooks()`.

Comment: Thank you! this should help anybody who has this problem in future.